# Difference between incremental DOM and virtual DOM in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom, frontend

I have two questions regarding Angular. I've tried reading some articles but I can't get the idea.

1. What is incremental DOM?
2. What is the difference between incremental DOM and virtual DOM?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Incremental DOM is a library for building up DOM trees and updating them in-place when data changes. It differs from the established virtual DOM approach in that no intermediate tree is created (the existing tree is mutated in-place). This approach significantly reduces memory allocation and GC thrashing for incremental updates to the DOM tree therefore increasing performance significantly in some cases.

https://github.com/google/incremental-dom

**Virtual DOM** compares (diff) a new entire virtual DOM with the previous virtual DOM for changes then applies those changes to the actual DOM. - This approach creates a new virtual DOM to determine the changes (memory heavy).

**Incremental DOM** has one virtual DOM and walks along the tree to find changes then mutates the virtual DOM and then apply those changes to the actual DOM - (reduced memory size and garbage collection).

Virtual DOM - has a big memory footprint because it needs headroom for changes that "might" happen to the virtual DOM.

Incremental DOM - doesn’t need such a big footprint as memory is only allocated for changes.

Tests have shown that Incremental DOM is fast enough to work even without a virtual DOM also.